# Error when using JS function replace in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need when cell for 'input' which are a list of numbers separated by comma ',' or blank space ' ' filled up, the next two cells will auto update with these numbers in ascending and descending orders subsequently.

I currently have error **input.replace is  not a function**. Any idea to fix the syntax? Thanks

```
 const [input, setInput] = useState('0')
    const [sortAscen, setSortAcen] = useState(input.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number).sort((a, b) => a - b).toString())
    const [sortDescen, setSortDescen] = useState(input.toString().replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number).sort((a, b) => b - a).toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a state that depends on another state. Instead, move your formatting logic to functions whose output can be used directly in your markup.

Comment: Hi, I fixed it but thank you anyway. replace() only works on string. When I edit to input.toString().replace(/, +/g, ","). ... it works well. Those code you see here are for setting up initial state only. I already had setInput, setAscen, setDescen wrapped in onChangeText to produce instant outputs afterwards